# how to add user roles dynamically upon login with symfony2 (and fosUserBundle)?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

In my app users can switch between free user and premium user over time, when their subscription expires, they no longer have premium previleges.

I thought I could cut a corner and not store the premium user role in the database, only store the date to which they have paid, thus eliminating the need for a cron job adding och removing the role premium from my users.

The solution I had in mind was to do this on the user entity:

```
public function __construct()
{
    if ( $this->hasPlus() )
    {       
        $this->addRole('ROLE_PLUSUSER');
    }
}
```

Where hasPlus is a function that compares the current date with the paid-to date and returns true if user has still paid.

Now, this doesn't work, so I was thinking maybe someone could shed light on this for me - I know roles are added upon login, and if I add a role after login I need to log out and back in for it to take effect, but here I am trying to add the role upon constructing my user object, still it doesn't work...

Added the eventListener as per the excellent answer below, still can't add the role to the user:

```
<?php

namespace Hemekonomi\UserBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session;


class SecurityListener
{
    protected $security;
    protected $session;

/**
* Constructs a new instance of SecurityListener.
*
* @param SecurityContext $security The security context
* @param Session $session The session
*/
    public function __construct(SecurityContext $security, Session $session)
    {
        //You can bring whatever you need here, but for a start this should be useful to you
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

/**
* Invoked after a successful login.
*
* @param InteractiveLoginEvent $event The event
*/
    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
         //Your logic needs to go here
         //You can addRole 
         //Even persist if you want but bring the right tools to your constructor
         $security = $this->security; 

         if ($security->getToken()->getUser()->hasPlus()) {       
            $security->getToken()->getUser()->addRole('ROLE_PLUSUSER');    
         }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your logic will not work on the `user` entity...

If what you want to achieve is upon login, use `Event Listeners`, that's why they are so useful :-)

What you will need to create is a Listener that reacts to the event `InteractiveLoginEvent`, something like this:

### 1/ Create a listener

```
<?php

namespace Acme\YourBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;


class SecurityListener
{
    protected $security;
    protected $session;

/**
* Constructs a new instance of SecurityListener.
*
* @param SecurityContext $security The security context
* @param Session $session The session
*/
    public function __construct(SecurityContext $security, Session $session)
    {
        //You can bring whatever you need here, but for a start this should be useful to you
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

/**
* Invoked after a successful login.
*
* @param InteractiveLoginEvent $event The event
*/
    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
         //Your logic needs to go here
         //You can addRole 
         //Even persist if you want but bring the right tools to your constructor
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that **InteractiveLoginEvent** is already created by default in Symfony (as you can see in the `use` statement) so there is very little to do now:

### 2/ Declare this listener as a service:

```
services:
    acme_your_bundle.listener.login:
        class: Acme\YourBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener
        arguments: [@security.context, @session]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onSecurityInteractiveLogin }
```

### 3/ Check the doc if you need to

[The Event Dispatcher Component](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html)

[How to create an Event Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html)

[Login Redirection by  Dustin Dobervich](http://www.dobervich.com/2011/10/13/login-redirection-revisited/): This post will give you a good example on how listeners work and how you can simply implement them upon login.

Comment: I followed all your instructions (thank you very much!) think you had a typo in the top of the entity, use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session was supposed to be use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session. But I don't get it to work, the function fires all right, but the role I want to add doesn't get added (I have tried the clause, it conditions true, see code above.)

Comment: Can you make sure `$security->getToken()->getUser()->hasPlus()` returns true for the user that is logging in?

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/symfony2/RIEfD7_5zIU), you can build a new security token and pass it to the security context using `->setToken()`. Otherwise, the UserProvider should have a `refreshUser()` method. You should be able to get the current user from the security context and then call the `refreshUser` method of the User Provider.

Comment: It does return true. I will try the refresh method and report back on my progress :-) thanks a lot!