# Dynamic roles in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, authorization, roles, event-listener

I have been trying to assign dynamic roles to users in my application. I tried to use an event listener to do that, but it just added the dynamic role for that one http request.

This is the function in my custom event listener that adds the role.

```
public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event) {

    $user = $this->security->getToken()->getUser();

    $role = new Role;
    $role->setId('ROLE_NEW');
    $user->addRole($role);
}
```

But I am not sure if this is even possible to do with event listeners. I just need to find a nice way how to add the roles for the whole time the user is logged. I would appreciate any help and suggestions.

Comment: You could try making a role provider that lasts for a session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this yet, but reading the cookbook this could work.

This example is a modified version of the example in the cookbook to accomodate for your requirements.

```
class DynamicRoleRequestListener
{
    public function __construct($session, $security)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) {
            // don't do anything if it's not the master request
            return;
        }

        if ($this->session->has('_is_dynamic_role_auth') && $this->session->get('_is_dynamic_role_auth') === true) {
            $role = new Role("ROLE_NEW"); //I'm assuming this implements RoleInterface
            $this->security->getRoles()[] = $role; //You might have to add credentials, too.
            $this->security->getUser()->addRole($role);
        }

        // ...
    }

    private $session;
    private $security;
}
```

And then you declare it as a service.

```
services:
    kernel.listener.dynamicrolerequest:
        class: Your\DemoBundle\EventListener\DynamicRoleRequestListener
        arguments: [@session, @security.context]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

A similar question is here: [how to add user roles dynamically upon login with symfony2 (and fosUserBundle)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283583/how-to-add-user-roles-dynamically-upon-login-with-symfony2-and-fosuserbundle)

Comment: Thanks, thats a nice way to do it. But there is one problem. The function "onKernelRequest" works fine, except the fact that when a page loads, it loads without css stylesheets. It looks like it is caused by trying to get the user. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Oh I have one more question. Since the new role is dynamic and is not persisted in the DB, when I use the function flush() anywhere in my app, I get an exception because of the role. It flushes the not persisted role and thats what I dont want to do. Is there a way to make it not try to flush the role?

Comment: Try using `detach` on the role and don't allow a cascade operation on the role collection.