# How to a dynamically add roles to a user?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.4

When a user logs in, whether it be for the first time or via a cookie that's present, I want to assign them one or more additional user roles based on the result of some queries I run.

I think I need to create an Event Listener that gets the security component and entity manager injected, so I can run my queries and add roles to the current user.

I'm not quite sure if this is possible with events though, since the event would need to be fired within the Firewall context before the authorization is done, but after authentication.

I did see [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283583), but I can't get it to work (the roles are not actually recognized after the event is run).

Is it possible to do this with an event listener?

I think my alternative would be to use a postload lifecycle callback on the `User` entity and run some queries there, but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Do you use FOSUserBundle?

Comment: I do not, I'm just using my own Doctrine [entity provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html). FOSUserBundle has a lot more features than I need (don't need registration, forgot password, etc)

Answer (score 7):

You could create an event listener on the kernel. It will run everytime a page is loaded.

It will check if their is a logged in user and then you can do some custom logic to see if you need to update their role, if you do then update it log them in with the new settings and then they'll continue in the system with their new role.

I haven't tested this code, so it might have some bugs.

services.yml

```
bundle.eventlistener.roles:
    class: Sample\MyBundle\EventListener\Roles
    arguments: [@service_container, @security.context]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

Listener\Roles.php

```
namespace Sample\MyBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

use Sample\MyBundle\Entity\Users; //Your USER entity

class Roles {
    private $container;
    private $context;

    public function __construct(Container $container, SecurityContext $context) {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event) {
        if($this->context->getToken()->getUser() instanceof Users) {

            //Custom logic to see if you need to update the role or not.

            $user = $this->context->getToken()->getUser();

            //Update your roles
            $user->setRole('ROLE_WHATEVER');

            $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            //Create new user token
            //main == firewall setting
            $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'main', $user->getRoles());

            $this->context->setToken($token);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to work through this approach. I'm using [this SSO bundle](https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle) which has a more complicated token, so it's not so easy to create a new one on the fly

Comment: Good luck, I haven't used that bundle before so I'm not sure what the correct syntax would be.